# Maintaining styling while cleaning html using JSoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I am very new to JSoup. And, I am using the following code to clean the html:

```
    String clean = Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.relaxed());
```

I am getting the the required html but all the styling such as bold, italics etc. are missing.

How i can maintain the html code with its respective styling using JSoup?
If there are any other library to do so, please recommend me one?

Comment: Can you add your sample html you're trying to clean up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `Jsoup.clean(html, Whitelist.relaxed())`,

**Whitelist.relaxed()**

Directly from the documentation,

> This whitelist allows a full range of text and structural body HTML: a, b, blockquote, br, caption, cite, code, col, colgroup, dd, dl, dt, em, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, i, img, li, ol, p, pre, q, small, strike, strong, sub, sup, table, tbody, td, tfoot, th, thead, tr, u, ul

if you want to make allow more elements (i.e. style atributes) add them to the `Whitelist` instance to allow through it. You can use the following methods from Whitelist API

```
addTags(java.lang.String...)
addAttributes(java.lang.String, java.lang.String...)
```

Please read the documentation of [Whitelist](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/) from JSOUP library.

Comment: Ah i see.Thanks for the suggestion.I will try to work around with your suggestion :D